# How to consume third party API with a API key inside the header

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0

I am been searching for a good way to implement API key inside the header of a "HttpGet" call to a third party API. I am retrieving data using Postman, but have not been successful using .net to do the call.

I been trying to add `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", "testApiToken");` to the header, but get authorization denied as feedback.

The data provided is mock-up but has the same structure.

Is there a special way to add the API key to the header?

The API key looks like this:

```
Key: 3tc97512-198y-12bt-847c-fdd50d583123
value: testApiToken
```

---

The code I tried to implement:

```
    namespace API.Controllers.GetUsersFromThirdPartyAPI
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class GetAllUsers : BaseApiController
    {
        private readonly DataContext _context;

        public GetAllUsers(DataContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://gate-api.hemsa.se:4004");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", "testApiToken");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/3tc97512-198y-12bt-847c-fdd50d583123/hms/hemsaRoster/v2p2/users");

            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please copy curl request from postman (via `Code` link on the right)?

Comment: @GuruStron curl --location 'https://gate-api.hemsa.se:4004/api/3tc97512-198y-12bt-847c-fdd50d583123/hms/hemsaRoster/v2p2/users' \
--header '3tc97512-198y-12bt-847c-fdd50d583123: testApiToken'

Comment: Try `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("3tc97512-198y-12bt-847c-fdd50d583123", "testApiToken");`

Comment: Was glad to help! Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide correct header name, which is (based on comments) - `3tc97512-198y-12bt-847c-fdd50d583123`:

```cs
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("3tc97512-198y-12bt-847c-fdd50d583123", "testApiToken");
```